# How to name an array of JLabels

Tags: java, arrays, jlabel

PLEASE NOTE: This question was a result of a weird bug in the compiler that magically disappeared. It is no confusing and no longer relevant. It has been flagged for moderator attention and is pending deletion.

I have created an `array` of **JLabels**. `private JLabel[] difference = new JLabel[10];`. The only issue is when I try to do something with them, it complains cause each element is set to `null`.

So I want to go through the `array` and name each value (ex: `difference[1]=difference1`, `difference[2]=difference2`, etc)

I would like to do something like the below, but it does not allow an int value or a string value for i.

```
for (int i=1; i<10; i++)
        {
            difference[i]=(difference+i);
        }
```

Then again, maybe the problem isn't what I thought it was, and the null issue is actually something else. Should `difference[1]` function as it's own variable?

Comment: Have you created the objects or just the array?

Comment: @IoannisMitrolios I am going to close this question as the behavior has suddenly inexplicably changed, and my original null problem is no longer present

Comment: The elements in the erray are not null becase you their lack of name. They are null because you haven't created any JLables and put them in the array.

Comment: The expression `new JLabel[10]` creates an array with space for 10 elements, all of which must be (references to) `JLabel`s.  It does not create any `JLabel`s; the elements all initially have the default value for a reference to an object : `null`.

Comment: Do you understand how JLabels work? In your loop, you need to create your JLabels using `new`. Then you can assign them a text/presentation value (JLabel.setText) or a name (JLabel.setName)

Comment: @ControlAltDel I have already done this

Comment: References are values, and they do not have or need names.  Names are a characteristic of *variables*, which may directly or indirectly contain references.  This is an aspect of how you can store and later recall the references you want, but any mechanism for doing so suffices, including, in some cases, mechanisms that never involve references being recorded in a variable at all.

Comment: So there was an error, it’s no longer there, and you don’t know what it was? In that case I suggest you delete the question. Nobody’s ever going to find it useful.

Comment: @OleV.V. Exactly. I have tried, but am not allowed, so I have flagged it for moderator attention

Comment: Thanks for taking this step.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have `JLabel`s: difference1, difference2, difference3 etc. Unfortunately `String` which is the same as the token that let's you access the variable called often variable name won't return a reference to the object.

Better approach will be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < difference.length; i++) {
    difference[i] = new JLabel();
}
```

Then you'll access the JLabels by `difference[i]`, where i is between 0 and `difference.length-1`.

Answer (score 0):

By specifying

> private JLabel[] difference = new JLabel[10];

You have just initialized the array that can refer to 10 JLabel instances (null by default). You need to loop through this array and use new operator before starting to work/use the difference array like

```
for(int i = 0; i < difference.length; i++)
   difference[i] = new JLabel();
```

Comment: anyway, my program was behaving strangely, but now functions as expected for no apperent reason.